# Why can Kubernetes not route a service on public ELB on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I've been trying to follow the example (`guestbook`) to reproduce another application which has to be available on a public interface.

This is my Kubernetes configuration (YAML):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-server
  labels:
    app: my-app-server
    tier: backend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-server
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-server
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ppm-server
        image: docker/container:tag
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        env:
        - name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
          value: dns
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myregistrykey
```

Not sure why this is not working.

The guestbook all-in-one example seems to work just fine though.

I tried using the exact same configuration file while just changing the variables in the configuration.

Comment: How did you setup your cluster? Make sure the CloudProvider is set to "AWS". If so need to make sure that you have proper IAM permissions to create the ELB.

Comment: @SteveSloka I was not able to solve this problem. I destroyed the cluster and created a new one (this time using CoreOS CloudFormation scritps). Surprisingly, it works. Haven't had time to dig deeper into the reason yet.